# Counting each elements in list string

Tags: python-2.7

I have a string -XX--XXX--XX- I'm trying to count each X and append it afterward. The above string should eventually be [2, 3, 2].
Here is a snippet of what I came up with:

```
knots = '-XX-XXX-XX-'

#Converting above string to ['XX', 'XXX', 'XX']
knots_without_dashes = knots.split('-')
```

For each 'X' in my list ['XX', 'XXX' and 'XX'] I want to count until the comma and append the result in an empty list without using counter library.

Comment: Hmm..I think you meant your output should be `[2, 3, 2]`?  Might want to edit the question!  Otherwise my answer is not correct.

Comment: yes edited my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[len(segment) for segment in knots.split('-') if len(segment)>0]
```

This will create a list made up of the length of each block that is separated by '-'.

Comment: Appreciate the help, this is exactly what I'm looking for to also solve the second half of the whole problem :)

Comment: NP!  It's a very 'pythonic' sort of a problem, so this feature, which is called a "list comprehension" is a typical solution.